# $E[X|W] = 0 \implies E[XW^{T}]=0$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $W \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ random vectors. Does $E[X|W] = 0 \implies E[XW^{T}]=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb E[XW^T]=\mathbb E\big[\mathbb E[XW^T\mid W]\big].$$